form `submit` event called when button type is `button`
I have a multistep form build with react-hook-form. The JSX is:
<form
  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onInvalidSubmit)}
  className="flex h-full w-full flex-col justify-between"
>
  <AnimatePresence mode="wait">{<step.content />}</AnimatePresence>
  <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between">
    <div className="">
      <Button
        onClick={back}
        variant="ghost"
        type="button"
        className={`${isFirstStep ? "invisible" : "visible underline"}`}
      >
        Poprzedni krok
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <div className="relative mt-4">
        <Button
          disabled={!step.canStep?.()}
          arrow={isLastStep ? undefined : "right"}
          gradient={true}
          type={isLastStep ? "submit" : "button"}
          onClick={() => !isLastStep && next()}
          className="hover:bg-initial"
        >
          {isLastStep && mutationCreateTeacherAcccount.isLoading && (
            <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />
          )}
          {isLastStep ? "Utwórz konto" : "Następny krok"}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>;

and the onSubmit callback is:
function onSubmit(data: RegisterTeacherSchemaType) {
  if (isLastStep) {
    mutationCreateTeacherAcccount.mutate(data);
  }
}

The problem is that in my 3-step form, when I click next during step 2, the step is properly set to 3 and hence the isLastStep is set to True and the button type changes from button to submit. This for some reason additionally trigger submit event on my form with isLastStep set to True which calls a mutation. Any ideas how can I fix my form to avoid that trigger? I wanted to trigger that event on the enxt click but now single click both changes the step number and trigger the form
The problem occurs as well when I rewrite that single button into two button:
{
  isLastStep ? (
    <Button
      disabled={!step.canStep?.()}
      gradient={true}
      type="submit"
      className="hover:bg-initial"
    >
      {mutationCreateTeacherAcccount.isLoading && (
        <Loader2 className="animate-spin" />
      )}
      {"Utwórz konto"}
    </Button>
  ) : (
    <Button
      disabled={!step.canStep?.()}
      arrow={"right"}
      gradient={true}
      type={"button"}
      onClick={() => next()}
      className="hover:bg-initial"
    >
      Następny krok
    </Button>
  );
}

EDIT
Strange, problem is solved when I use onMouseDown instead of onClick. Any ideas why it might be the case? And is that correct solution?

Does the issue still exist if you add different key to both submit and button?

it doesnt! Thanks a lot!!
